# How to create a permanent alias without resourcing the .bashrc-like file?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I really like bash aliases, it annoys me that every time I want to add a new alias I have type two commands:

```
echo "alias \"short-cmd\"='long-command'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Any way I can create an alias permanently with a single command?

Comment: You can use `.` instead of `source` and press [Alt]+[.] to insert the last argument of the previous command, so you can do the equivalent of `source ~/.bash_aliases.sh` in just four keystrokes without the need for any custom functions.

Comment: The point is do everything in a single command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my workaround, the function `palias` (aka permanent alias):

```
function palias ()  {

    if [ $# -ne "2" ] ; then
        error "Usage: palias short-alias \'long-alias\'"
        return
    fi

    alias $1="$2"
    alias $1 >> ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

Comment: FYI: Running `alias` without a definition will show the current definition. You can use this to make sure the quoting works right—e.g., your current method fails if the definition contains single-quote. `alias "$1" >> ~/.bash_aliases` does not. I suggest switching (in both your answer and on your systems). Also, you shouldn't be using `echo -e` there; you want plain `echo` (if you don't want to switch to `alias` for some reason).

Comment: @derobert I solved some expansion problems and applied the alias trick you told me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My "two keystroke solution" (one letter and the return key) is to have this alias set up:

```
alias a='. ~/.bash_aliases'
```

Then whenever I update my .bash_aliases file I just type `a`<kbd>return</kbd>

One step further is maintain them across machines, using github:

```
bup () { [ $# = 1 ] && { cp -v ~/$1 ~/Dropnot/setups; cd ~/Dropnot/setups; git fetch; git merge origin/master; git add $1; git commit -m"$1 update"; git push origin master; cp -v $1 ~; cd -; } || echo "Error - no filename passed!";}
```

Usage: `bup [file] # file must be in ~, is usually a dot file]`

Answer (score -2):

There are several files that run when you login to your shell including ~/.bash_profile and possibly ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_aliases if those are referenced in your ~/.bash_profile file.  To have an alias available every time you login, just put the command that creates the alias in one of those files.

http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

Comment: I know that! The point is to make it permanent without resourcing any file